# JavaScript: Argument passing doesn't work on all browsers

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I'm trying to pass an argument to a function, which works fine on Chrome but not on all versions of Firefox. Here's the code :

```
  $('input').focus(function()
  {
     alert(this.width);
   });
```

this.width appears to be undefined on some versions of FF.

Please help me.

Comment: @nnnnnn, those comments are good candidates for the answer ;)

Comment: OK @ted, since you "insist": comments deleted and posted as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, it seems the problem has nothing to do with passing an argument to a function, it's just that `this.width` is undefined in some browsers? I couldn't find documentation for `width` as a property of an input element, so it doesn't surprise me that it doesn't work consistently.

Have you tried [`this.offsetWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.offsetWidth)? Or `this.style.width`?

Or given that you seem to be using jQuery you might also look at [`$(this).width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/).